# What is a hook and how does it differ from a pipeline processor?

Tags: pipelines, hooks

The title says it all: what is a hook and how does it differ from a pipeline processor?

Specifically, I am looking for the following:

- What is a hook?
- How/when are hooks triggered?
- What are hooks used for?
- How do hooks differ from pipeline processors?

Comment: I can only guess that the downvotes have been due to the content length of the question, so I added some more specific details that i'm looking for. If there is something else wrong with the question, please let me know so that I can fix it :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Hooks**

A *hook* is a mechanism that you can use to run or "register" some logic at initialization time. To create one, you implement the `IHook` interface and add the necessary configuration as determined by your implemented hook. Hooks are loaded and executed when the application is initialized, via the `Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.LoadHooks` processor of the `<initialize>` pipeline.

Hooks are typically used for situations when you have some initialization-time logic that needs to be run but doesn't really belong within the `<initialize>` pipeline and doesn't depend on a context. For example, Sitecore uses hooks OOTB for health monitoring and memory checking.

Hooks are especially useful when you have a recurring task that you want to set up to run on a time interval. For example, if you want to ping a service on a set time interval and you do not require any site or item context then a Hook may be what you need.

Mike Reynolds has a great [blog post](https://sitecorejunkie.com/2013/01/22/get-hooked-on-hooks-create-a-custom-hook-in-sitecore/) describing what a hook is and how you can implement one, and I highly recommend it for additional details.

**Hooks vs. Pipeline Processors**

Remember that Hooks are loaded and executed in the `<initialize>` pipeline, but they are not processors. Hooks don't require any Sitecore context, and they do not have any arguments. As such, hooks are lighter-weight than processors and thus better suited for smaller tasks that don't depend on a context.

This [blog post](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/all-about-initialization-hooks-in-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms) by John West is a good resource for additional information on the differences between a Hook and a Pipeline Processor.

Comment: Further, since all the hooks are executed through a single processor, it's quite easy to disable the entire set in one fell swoop.  I suspect this is just some legacy functionality that has been superseded by the `<initialize />` pipeline.  Can anyone confirm that suspicion?

Comment: That is true. You can disable the processor